# Unity Android take a pic using camera and augment a 3d object on it

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Kindly share the steps or reference tutorial for 
1. when i open the app, camera should be opened and should allow to take a picture.
2. As soon as i click a picture a 3d object must be augmented on top of it.
Example: i should be able to click a pic of my hand via camera and augment a 3d image (engagement ring) on top of the clicked picture.

Thanks in advance for your valuable guidance

Comment: You'd have to first try something before you can ask for help. In your case, look into how to access camera on android and take snapshot https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html you have the GetPixels method or Application.ScreenCapture. Then just place a model over the texture in your scene.

Comment: Do you mean I need to capture an image in android using android programing and then augment an image using unity?

Comment: Not necessarily, it could be a solution but other wise you can use the WebCamTexture. Application.ScreenCapture is Unity API.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using vuforia. Its simple and very useful.

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-ar-android-app-with-vuforia-and-unity/